# Best Way to make one section of a LI editable

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

What is the best way to make JUST card.price editable? I've futzed around with several different ways that seemed stupid simple, but it just isn't producing the right results. Does anyone out there have some suggestions?

```
html += "<li class='list-item ui-state-default' id=" + i + ">" +
    card.card_name + ' - ' + card.price +
    "<button class='removeThis'>" +
    "X" + "</button>" + "</li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do that with `input` elements.  Simplified example to illustrate it:

```js
var card = {};
  card.card_name = "Card Name";
  card.price = "4.00";

var inputBeg = "<input size=8 style='border: none;' value='$";
var inputEnd = "'>";
var html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  html += "<li class='list-item ui-state-default' id=" + i + ">" + 
  card.card_name + ' - ' + inputBeg + card.price + inputEnd + "<button class='removeThis'>" + 
  "X" + "</button>" + "</li>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

You could get much fancier with the styling if you wanted to.